# Plot with special special gridlines

Tags: plotting, grid-lines

I would like to plot a function in plane with axes grid-lines labeled as follows, $1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{4},\sqrt{5},\ldots$, instead of the usual 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ....

[image: grid]

Comment: What is the problem with the [`GridLines`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GridLines.html) option? This can be found directly in the help...

Comment: Why not do `GridLines -> {{1, Sqrt[2], (* … *)}, Automatic}`? For labels, look up how to set `Ticks` or `FrameTicks`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might work for you.

```
ticks = 
  Module[{val},
    val = Sign[x] Sqrt[Abs[x]];
    Table[{val, Style[val, Background -> White]}, {x, -5, 5}]];
With[{max = Sqrt[6.]},
  Plot[{}, {x, -max, max},
    Ticks -> {ticks, ticks},
    PlotRange -> {{-max, max}, {-max, max}},
    AspectRatio -> Automatic,
    GridLines -> {ticks[[All, 1]], ticks[[All, 1]]}]]
```

[image: grid]

Answer (score 5):

This is not ideal. The tick label overlap but perhaps it can facilitate better approaches, e.g. custom tick label placement (e.g. alternating heights, rotation etc)...

**EDIT**

I have removed my aesthetically poor choice of coloring but post hopefully more acceptable coloring (with aforementioned limitations):

```
 With[{val = Sqrt /@ Range[7], 
  lab = Style[Sqrt[#], 6, Bold, Background -> White] & /@ Range[7], 
  nlab = Style[-Sqrt[#], 6, Bold, Background -> White] & /@ Range[7], 
  tp = Table[{0, 0.02}, {14}]},
 Graphics[{LightPink, Point[{0, 0}]}, 
  PlotRange -> Table[{-3, 3}, {2}], Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Thick, 
  Ticks -> Table[
    Transpose[{val~Join~(-val), lab~Join~nlab, tp}], {2}], 
  GridLines -> Table[val~Join~(-val), {2}], Background -> White, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Gray]]
```

[image]

Comment: uh, my eyes... cannot... see... colors... hurt...

Comment: @YvesKlett apolgies Yves Klett...I will remove...agree ugly...probably reflects my mood...:)

Comment: Don´t worry, actually that got me smiling, reminding me of those 80´s web page layouts that brought tears to many a surfer´s eye :D

Comment: @YvesKlett...its been a 'psychedelic' week for me...:)

Comment: I must confess: I would have downvoted this if you hadn't changed the color scheme. :P

Comment: @J. M....back to coloring books for me :)

Comment: @J. M. let me guess... Tufte´s the word ;-)

Comment: hmmm... you in the pharma biz? Any samples left?

Comment: @YvesKlett...more remedial reading...not pharma...close...referring more to mind altering effects of 20 hours on the job...not sure whether it was rose coloured glasses or blood soaked...would have preferred Van Gogh yellows...btw I love you engineering origami...'magical' :)

Comment: Thank you! Were times I also got my vision hazing properly due to crease overload (and let's *not* get started on papercuts!)  :-)